# Annoying user password authentication every time I open a picture

Tags: permissions, password, file-sharing, ownership

I transferred pictures via pscp from Windows to my Ubuntu VM, but every time I open the pictures inside my VM, it asks for a password TWICE. I thought it's about the ownership, so I tried using `chmod` and `chown`, but it still requires me to enter my password. Is there any way to open the pictures without authentication?

`ls -l` and `stat` here:

[image: 'ls -l' and 'stat' here]

Comment: How / with what do you open the pictures ?

Comment: Sidenote: when you want to share _text_ with us then it's far better to share it actually as text and not as a photograph of text. That way we could copy and paste it instead of having to retype it, in case we wanted to reproduce something. Also, _text_ can be indexed by all currently known search engines.

Comment: @SorenA whenever I double click the pictures, Image viewer pops out. It should be the default image viewer for ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @PerlDuck thanks for the tip on how to post questions here.

Comment: You're welcome. I would guess you once ran your image viewer with `sudo` (i.e. as root). Then it wrote back its configuration as user `root` and now you cannot use it properly as non-root. Might that be the case?

Comment: @PerlDuck I will check if that is the case. Although I've never touched any configuration files except for nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

The picture files have the executable bit set. If you double click on them, they will be treated as an actual binary instead of a picture.

Have you tried to remove the "x" bit from all picture files?
Most likely this is a pscp issue (setting all bits on transferred files).

Comment: Good guess, but I think they have `777` because the OP, in his despair, `chmod`ded them to avoid that annoying password prompt. If I `chmod 777 some.jpeg` then doubleclicking just opens it as normal.

Comment: you mean like removing the execute permision by doing `chmod 666 picture.jpg`? As PerlDuck says, I did `chmod 777 *` all of them.0

Comment: @klifford-agujar what happens If you open the image viewer first and inside the viewer the actual file ?